# Xcode malloc error - stack looks weird

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, malloc

I'm using cocos2d and I load all my sprites and scenes before my game. However, once loaded, it seems if I click to start the game too quickly I get this crash:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x65cdbb4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So I did what it suggested, recreated the crash and the stack shows this:

```
#0 0x9033df7e in malloc_error_break ()
#1 0x9033f128 in szone_error ()
#2 0x9033f29b in free_list_checksum_botch ()
#3 0x9024c186 in tiny_malloc_from_free_list ()
#4 0x9024b2a1 in szone_malloc_should_clear ()
#5 0x9024b148 in malloc_zone_malloc ()
#6 0x90249218 in malloc ()
#7 0x97145617 in operator new ()
#8 0x03adc43f in llvm::User::operator new ()
#9 0x03aab18f in llvm::CastInst::Create ()
#10 0x0341394c in llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseFunctionBody ()
#11 0x034164fe in llvm::BitcodeReader::materializeFunction ()
#12 0x0cd72472 in glvmAddOperation ()
#13 0x0cd4c752 in gleBuildVertexSubmitFunc ()
#14 0x0cd74e0c in cvmsModularBuilder ()
#15 0x03392a67 in cvmsCompBuildModularFunction ()
#16 0x033970a8 in cvmsServerBuildModularFunction ()
#17 0x03394e26 in CVMSBuildModularFunction ()
#18 0x032b0c26 in glvm_deferred_build_modular ()
#19 0x03310404 in glvmDoWork ()
#20 0x902747fd in _pthread_start ()
#21 0x90274682 in thread_start ()
```

None of these functions listed are mine, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you list your code near the crash? The touch handler you mention...

Comment: Ok turns out I was releasing something there after I switched the scene. Can't believe I didn't look, well done you.